# convert table 6 rows to 2 rows and 3 columns using existing class

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Is there a way to convert existing 6 row table to 2 rows and 3 columns using existing class. I dont have access to html files. Can only add stylesheet to existing classes

```
<table cellspacing="0">
        <tbody><tr>
              <td class="class1"><label for="radio0">
                <input type="radio" checked="" value="1" name="name" id="radio0">1
                </label></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="class2"><label for="radio1">
                <input type="radio" value="8" name="name" id="radio1">2
                </label></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="class3"><label for="radio2">
                <input type="radio" value="12" name="name" id="radio2">3
                </label></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="class4"><label for="radio3">
                <input type="radio" value="4" name="name" id="radio3">4
                </label></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="class5"><label for="radio4">
                <input type="radio" value="7" name="name" id="radio4">5
                </label></td>
            </tr>
        <tr>
              <td class="class6"><label for="radio5">
                <input type="radio" value="5" name="name" id="radio5">6
                </label></td>
            </tr>

        </tbody></table>
```

Comment: I think you have to use JS to solve this problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could always position the elements to be absolute, but I want to warn you that it may not stay consistent.. And this is only altering the CSS as well. The example is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ftS2A/1/)

CSS:

```
.class3{
    position:absolute;
        margin-left: 40px;
    top: 9px;
}
.class4{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 40px;
    top: 30px;
}
.class5{
    position:absolute;
        margin-left: 80px;
    top: 9px;
}
.class6{
    position:absolute;
    margin-left: 80px;
    top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: I'm also glad it worked :) You may find that a JS solution would work better for the future if you have any access to it!